# Vaadin - SVG Generator, any alternative?

Tags: svg, charts, vaadin

I have been working with Vaadin charts during this week and I found a problem that I cannot solve. I need to send several charts to a PDF generation (using iTextpdf) and I could do it using SVGGenerator. The main problem is I cannot use this solution because the final laptop doesn't allow any installation, and Phantomjs is required for SVG Generator (no add-on can be installed neither). I tried to find a different solution to convert the chart content into file or buffer that I can manage, but I think I have been reading so much posts and I am not able to distinguish the solution.

So, I will try to clarify basic questions first:

a) Is it possible to manage SVG Generator without any installation in the laptop?

b) If not, is there a different way to convert a chart into an object which class could be managed to insert it into a PDF?

I can assure you I tried to read all documentation in this forum and official Vaadin forum related to this topic but I couldn't find any solution. I don't want to seem lazy, I only want to avoid spending more time and clarify the maining pre-conditions to solve this issue.

thanks in advance for your time and help.

Kind regards,

David.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a screenshot of your chart and append it to pdf:

```
        Screenshot screenshot = new Screenshot();
        screenshot.setTargetComponent(myTargetComponent);
        myChartLayout.addComponent(screenshot);

        //when complete 
        screenshot.addScreenshotListener(new ScreenshotListener() {
            public void screenshotComplete(ScreenshotImage image) {
                //do something 
            }
        });

        //take screenshot
        screenshot.takeScreenshot();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to render a Vaadin Chart without a web browser engine of some kind. That's what PhantomJS provides. If you have a full-blown web browser at your disposal, though, you can grab the SVG markup manually from there; it's just a bit more difficult to automate. This works in Chrome:

1. Open your Charts app in the browser
2. Open the JavaScript console (Ctrl/Cmd + Shift + J)
3. Type something like this: `copy(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].outerHTML)`
4. Paste the contents of your clipboard to a new text file and save it as an SVG.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install phantomjs, just bundle its binary along with your web application ([Reference](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)). I did the same thing with my Amazon AWS deployment and it works just fine.